# SQL server :Grouping them based on a Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table in the below manner:

```
ID , sales
1, 1
2, 1
3, 2
4, 2
5, 3
6, 2
7, 3
8, 5
9, 9
10, 3
11, 2
```

what i want to basically achieve is i want to group the id based on their sales into 3 groups : High, med, low

o/p

```
ID, sales, group
1, 1, low
2, 1, low
3, 2, low
4, 2, low
5, 3, low
6, 2, low
7, 3, low
8, 5, med
9, 9, high
10, 3, low
11, 2, low
```

Comment: And wha tare the rules for the three groups?

Comment: just bucketing the ids into 3 groups by their sales, limit has to be caluculated

Comment: Explain to us your current output.  Why is 3 the threshold for low, and what are the dividers for medium and high?

Answer (score 1):

Select the maximum of `sales` and divide it by 3. Use that in a `CASE` to rank your sales figures.

```
SELECT id,
       sales,
       CASE
         WHEN sales <= convert(decimal, (SELECT max(sales)
                                                FROM elbat))
                       / 3
           THEN 'low'
         WHEN sales <= convert(decimal, (SELECT max(sales)
                                                FROM elbat))
                       / 3 * 2
           THEN 'med'
         ELSE 
           'high'
       END group
       FROM elbat;
```

Just to demonstrate the idea. You might want to tweak it regarding the operators (e.g. `<` instead of `<=`) and the calculation, e.g. apply `ceil()` to the result, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when sales < 4 then 'low'
             when sales < 7 then 'med'
             else 'high'
        end) as sales_group
```

Comment: in the case i know the limits but its a huge data set i do not know the limits, it has to calculate itself

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` clause :

```
select t1.sales_group, count(*) as counts, sum(t.sales) as total_sales_group
from table t
cross apply ( values (case when sales < 4 then 'low'
                           when sales < 7 then 'med'
                           else 'high'
                       end) 
            ) t1 (sales_group)
group by t1.sales_group;
```